# In Angular 2, how do I convert Date to yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000Z format?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, iso8601

I have a component that handles dates in this format that I put in the title, I can convert from '2020-06-19T03: 00: 00.000Z' to Date, but I can't convert from Date to '2020-06-19T03: 00: 00.000Z ', how to carry out this conversion?

Comment: Your format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), nothing Java specific, so I put this tag instead of the java tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no Angular question, as it should be done in plain Javascript.
You can use the "Date.toISOString()" function as described here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-toisostring-function/

Whenever you have to deal with date and time in Javascript you should have a look at the moment.js library (https://momentjs.com/), which is pretty lightweight and offers a lot of helper and formatter functions which make your life easier.